# Race condition in React setState and Promise

Tags: reactjs

In my Context I have a `LocalFunction` that returns a promise.

```
LocalFunction: () => Promise<void>

LocalFunction: () => {
    return externalCall.getBooks().then((books) => {
        this.setState({ Books: books })
    })
}
```

I can call this function in another component based on the updated `Books` object in the Context state like:

```
this.props.LocalFunction().then(() => {
    // do something with this.props.Context.Books
})
```

But I know React updates states in batches. So could I run into a race condition when calling LocalFunction without the `Books` state being updated with the new books?

I know a way to avoid it is to wrap LocalFunction in a new Promise and resolve it in `this.setState({ Books: books }, resolve)`, but I wanna avoid doing that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

How about to use async/await?

```
LocalFunction: async (needUpdate = false) => {
    const result = await externalCall.getBooks();
    if(needUpdate){
        this.setState({ Books: result })
    }
    return result;
}
```

```
this.props.LocalFunction().then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
    // do something with this.props.Context.Books
})
```

When you need to update state

```
LocalFunction(true)
```